# Disable chart title editing AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm currently trying out AG-Grid and I can't seem to disable title editing in the charts.

Have a look at the plnkr and double click on the title of each chart and see what I mean.

https://plnkr.co/edit/2e8RxPabCWKJdzsn?open=main.ts&preview

I'm thinking that it should be something along the lines of this:

```
    title: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            editable: false,
            }
```

but i cant seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the actual title to `font-size:0` and adding a subtitle. Setting `enabled: false` on the title does not work. Apparently the title is mandatory to show the subtitle.

```
title: 
    {
        enabled: true,
        fontSize: 0,
    },
subtitle: 
    {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'YOUR TITLE HERE',
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#666666',
    },
```